# flutter url_launcher plugin causing the problem

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':url_launcher:createFullJarDebug'.

  > File 'C:\Users\Narender\AndroidStudioProjects\the_makeable_app\build\url_launcher\intermediates\runtime_library_classes\debug\classes.jar' specified for property 'libraryInputFile' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Any fix for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve error "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71249591/how-to-solve-error-failure-build-failed-with-an-exception)