# How to solve error "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception"?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, terminal, build-error

Task :app:makeProjectDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:makeProjectDebug'.

A problem occurred starting process 'command 'make''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gradle commands such as gradlew build --stacktrace or --debug to find out the root cause . This will give you the exact exception if any dependencies or resource file is causing the issue